# When truncating a 64 bit address to a 32 bit address in windows, why do we need to guarantee that the high 33 bits are 0, and not the high 32 bits?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I've been reading Windows via C/C++ by Jeffrey Richter and came across the following snippet in the chapter about Windows' memory architecture related to porting 32 bit applications to a 64 bit environment.

> If the system could somehow guarantee that no memory allocations would every be made above 0x00000000'7FFFFFFF, the application would work fine. Truncating a 64 bit address to a 32 bit address when the high 33 bits are 0 causes no problem whatsoever.

I'm having some trouble understanding why the system needs to guarantee that no memory allocations are made above `0x00000000'7FFFFFFF` and not `0x00000000'FFFFFFFF`. Shouldn't it be okay to truncate the address so long as the high `32` bits are `0`? I'm probably missing something and would really appreciate it if someone with more knowledge about windows than me could explain why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all 32bit systems/languages use unsigned values for memory addresses, so the 32th bit might have different meaning in some contexts. By limiting the address space to 31 bits, you don't run into that problem.  And also, Windows limits a 32bit app from accessing addresses higher than 2 GB without the use of special extensions to extend that, so most apps would not need the 32th bit anyway.

Comment: ah I see, I didn't realize it could have something to do with signedness. That makes sense. Thanks for the answer!